# Cant understand excel formular

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula, formulas

I have two value which gives me a total in excel.

But i dont understand the formula and i have to convert it into javascript, to make it work on html

```
 value1 =  33.238;
 value2 = 30%;
 formula = value1/(1-value2);
 total =  47.483
```

Does someone understand this formula in excel so I can translate it into javacript?

I thought 30% of 33.238 was 9.971 and total is 43.209 but this formula on excel makes me confused...

this is what I have in my code

```
    var margin = 30;
    var margin_total = parseInt((+overhead_plus_hh * +margin)/100);
    var total = +overhead_plus_hh + +margin_total;
```

but im not getting dame results as the excel formula.

Comment: 30% is `0.3` and `1 - 0.3` is 0.7, so `33.238 / 0.7` is 47.4828571429..

Comment: thanks @Slai now I understood the formula and I was able to replicate it into javascript!!

Answer (score 0):

This was the fix to my code:

```
    var total = parseInt(+overhead_plus_hh / (1-(+margin/100)));
```

thanks to slai for taking the time to help me understan the excel formula.